# WebAPI C# Routing

Tags: c#, asp.net-web-api

I have two end points:

- `api/v1/user/session` (For creating user login with post request )
- `api/v1/user` (For creating user with post request)

How to route this two endpoints in same controller? I also want to specify action for a specific request. More clearly:

all get,post,update, patch operations can be done in api/v1/user/session endpoint

all get,post,update, patch operations can be done in api/v1/user endpoint

Is it possible ?

Example:

```
config.Routes.MapHttpRoute(
    "UserApi",
    "api/v1/{controller}/session",
    new { controller = "User", action="Session" });
```

Now, I want all rest requests to work for Session method with [httpPost],[httpGet] etc attributes.

```
       config.Routes.MapHttpRoute("lol", "api/v1/{controller}/session", 
            new { controller = "User", action="Session" });

        //config.Routes.MapHttpRoute(
        //    name: "LoginApi",
        //    routeTemplate: "api/v1/{controller}",
        //    defaults: new { controller = "User"}
        //);

        config.Routes.MapHttpRoute(
            name: "RailStationApi",
            routeTemplate: "api/v1/{controller}/{id}",
            defaults: new { id = RouteParameter.Optional }
        );
```

Comment: It is entirely possible. It would be helpful to see what you have tried so we can see where you're having some trouble.

Comment: @dmsbilas Could you edit your question to show us all of the (relevant) routes you have? Routes are evaluated _in the order in which they were added to the Routes collection_, so it would be good if we could see the bigger picture of what you've done.

Comment: I have created UserController. I want api/user/session endpoint will have all [httpGet], [httpPost] etc working for this specific session method.

I also have another end poin  api/user endpoint. after adding my routing, my api/user/session routing works, but api/user routing doesn't work.

Comment: http://www.asp.net/web-api/overview/web-api-routing-and-actions/attribute-routing-in-web-api-2

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I tried with hardcoded solution and it worked. I added following route into the webapi.config file and it worked.

```
RouteTable.Routes.MapHttpRoute(
            name: "SessionApi",
            routeTemplate: "api/v1/user/session",
            defaults: new { Controller = "Session", id = RouteParameter.Optional }
        ).RouteHandler = new SessionStateRouteHandler();
```

Answer (score 5):

I would suggest you look at [attribute routing](http://www.asp.net/web-api/overview/web-api-routing-and-actions/attribute-routing-in-web-api-2) - this is a lot easier to specify than using the central configuration.

```
[RoutePrefix("api/v1")]
public class UserController : ApiController {

    [HttpPost]
    [Route("user/session")]
    public void Login(/*...*/) {
        // ...
    }

    [HttpGet]
    [Route("user/session")]    // Note this has the same route as Login
    public SessionResult GetSession(/*...*/) {
        // ...
    }

    [HttpPost]
    [Route("user")]
    public void CreateUser(/*...*/) {
        // ...
    }

}
```

Note that you don't technically need `[HttpPost]` since it is the default, but I included it for clarity.  You can add methods with the other Http verbs in the same way.